# Deriving derivative of $\ln x$ without letting $h=\alpha x$

Tags: derivatives, logarithms, solution-verification

Where is the error in this derivation of the derivative of $f(x)=\ln x$?

$$f'(x)=\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{\ln(x+h)-\ln x}{h}=\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{\ln\left(\frac{x+h}{x}\right)}{h}=\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{\ln\left(1+\frac{h}{x}\right)}{h}$$

$$=\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\ln\left(1+\frac{h}{x}\right)^{1/h}=?$$

Comment: How'd you jump from the last step on the first line to the last step?

Comment: The power law of logarithms:  $\log_b x^n = n\log_bx$.

Comment: This derivation has no errors. The last limit is $e^{1/x}$ by taking $y = 1/h \to \infty$

Comment: @fGDu94 Perhaps you could turn that into an answer.

Comment: sure i will do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything in the proof is correct so far.
Final step:

$\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\ln\left(1+\frac{h}{x}\right)^{1/h} = \lim_{y \to \infty} \ln ((1+\frac{1}{xy})^y = \ln(e^{\frac{1}{x}}) = \frac{1}{x}$